# Problemas con los Cors en Laravel y Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de enviar la información desde AngularJ hasta mi apirest de L5 la información es del Login e users con su password el error es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado por minutos aplicar varios package de L5 con relacion a este error y nada que me a dado resultado. La version de L5 es las 5.1

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro. Si miras la respuesta verás que la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` esta puesta 3 veces con el valor `*`, `*` y `http://localhost:9000`. Tienes que revisar que configuración de tu servidor esta poniendo las cabeceras y eliminarla. Edita la pregunta y agrega información relevante de la configuración de tu servidor.

Comment: Como los dice devconcept, puede que tengas un interceptor o algo que este agregando más de una vez el header de `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  ¿tienes algo como Laravel Debugger o algo similiar activado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que modificar la configuración en tu servidor para que pueda aceptar solicitudes desde un dominio distinto.

Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script. Te recomiendo usar el paquete [CORS laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).

Además, asegurate de desactivar la verificación del CSRF token (remueve `'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` en `app/Http/Kernel.php`).

Comment: El problema de la pregunta es que tiene mas de una cabecera puesta, tu respuesta lo solucionaría si no tuviera ninguna configuración activada. Creo que ayudaría mas si incluyeras en tu respuesta un ejemplo de como debería ser dicha configuración. Quizás de esta forma el OP pueda darse cuenta de donde esta el problema. Saludos.